# Why is new Date() a string value?

Tags: javascript, object

Normally, when I call `new` keyword, it will absolutely output an object. For example:

```
function Time(){
    this.now = new Date();
}
console.log(new Time());
//{now : 'Tue Aug 26 2014 01:52:15 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)'}
```

How can `new Date()` be a string value?

Comment: Regarding your code comment, it s an object ;) not a string ( note the brackets)

Comment: That's just the console converting it for you to view. Try `new Date() instanceof Date` and `new Date() instanceof String`.

Comment: `{...}` is an object, which console.log is politely printing out at in human readable string format for you...

Comment: .toString() implicitly gets called

Comment: @ajp15243 To be fair though, `"" instanceof String` is also false. ;)

Comment: @cdhowie Of course, it's a string literal

Comment: @cdhowie Silly JavaScript

Comment: @Johan At "string literal" is a language term that has no meaning at runtime; the literal is used to create a string object at runtime.  There is no distinction at runtime between a string that was created from a literal and one that was created some other way.  But to prove this to you, even non-literal strings aren't instances of `String`: `("a" + "b") instanceof String` is still false.

Comment: @cdhowie But `new String() instanceof String` is true, so why the differentiation between using the constructor and using literals?

Comment: @ajp15243 That's part of the fun of JavaScript. `typeof "" === "string"` but `typeof new String("") === "object"`.  A `String` instance isn't really a string value.

Comment: using "new " forces object output on String, Number, Boolean, and Date. Sometimes you want a String object, but usually a primitive works just fine because it's silently upgraded to an object if need be.

Comment: Interesting, apparently [JavaScript has primitive types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects), where string, boolean, and number primitives (created with literals and non-`new` constructor use) are distinct from their object counterparts (created with `new` and a constructor call). I never knew this difference explicitly until now.

Comment: @cdhowie I know that they aren't instances of a `String`, but they are still temporarily promoted in to a `String` object when required.

Comment: @Johan Of course. I was merely pointing out that ajp15243's `new Date() instanceof String` is actually not a 100% useful test without the corresponding `(typeof new Date()) === "string"` to cover the primitive case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer:

It isn't.

In your console type:

```
typeof new Date()
```

where it correctly returns `"object"`

However, the object returned as a method called `toString()` which will return ... a string.

```
var date = new Date();
console.log(typeof date)
console.log(date.toString())


object
Mon Aug 25 2014 14:58:28 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

*Edit:  In an odd twist of the JavaScript API, `typeof Date()` does return `"string"`.  Note the missing `new` keyword.*

Answer (score 1):

`new Date()` does return an object as you expect, not a string.

```
> typeof new Date()
"object"

> typeof "some string"
"string"
```

`console.log()` must necessarily produce a string. If an object to be logged provides a stringification method (`toString`), `console.log()` will use it to produce a readable log entry.